# 3D Voronoi with Internal Geometry?

Tags: modeling, geometry, subdivision-surface, 3d-printing, wireframe

I want to 3D print a model of a vertebra for my brother but I wanted to spice it up and print it in a voronoi style. I'm aware that this can be done by adding wiremesh and sub surf modifiers.

The problem I have with this is that the model is then a shell of what it was, and I'd rather it looked filled-in like bone matrix.

*How can I make a 3D voronoi of the model I have **with randomly generated internal geometry**.*

As a side note, the wiremesh modifier ignores any internal geometry - I did try manually adding some and wiremeshing it.

Here is an example image of what I mean:

[image: Example of what I want]

Any help would be very much appreciated!

J

Comment: I know Tissue addon could generate stuff like this, but I'm not aware of what the final geometry looks like.

Answer (score 4):

Something can be done with **Cell Fracture** addon, *Merge by Distance*, *Delete by Limited Disolve*, *Delete Only Faces* ... you end up with just edges ... ad *Skin*, *Remesh*, *Smooth* modifier in this order.

[image]

If *Skin* modifier ignores some edges, go to *Edit* mode and select some of this ignored vertex and *Mark as Root*.

Anyway for such model like your (Dear with this cell size) it could be a calculation killer :) I'm posting it just as a tip before some geo-nodes guru comes to help here :)